# Manually deriving the type of fun xss = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss

Tags: haskell, types, unification

I'm trying to manually derive the type of `fun xss = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss`

**f . y**

```
y :: t1 -- First occurrence
f :: t2 -- First occurrence

(.) (b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1 -- (.) definition

t1 ~ a1 -> b1 -- y unified with (a1 -> b1)
t2 ~ b1 -> c1 -- y unified with (b1 -> c1)

y :: a1 -> b1
f :: b1 -> c1
---
f . y :: a1 -> c1 -- Cancellation rule
```

**\f -> let ope x y = x . f . y**

```
(.) (b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2 -- (.) definition

x :: t3 -- First occurrence

t3 ~ b2 -> c2 -- x unified with (b2 -> c2)
a1 -> c1 ~ a2 -> b2 -- f . y unified with (a2 -> b2)

a1 ~ a2
c1 ~ b2

y :: a2 -> b1 -- Substituing a1 by a2
f :: b1 -> b2 -- Substituing c1 by b2
x :: b2 -> c2 -- Substituing t3 by b2 -> c2
---
x . f . y :: a2 -> c2 -- Cancellation rule
(\f -> let ope x y :: x . f . y) 
          :: (b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b1) -> (b1 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2 -- Adding f
```

**foldr1 ope xss**

```
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a -- foldr1 definition

xss ~ t4 -- First occurrence
```

Then `a ~ (b2 -> c2), a ~ (a2 -> b1), a ~ (b1 -> b2) and t4 ~ [a]` which seems to be an error.

Any help?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Comment: Your problem is in the last passage in the second block. What you actually want to know is the type of `ope`, which you can then unify with the `foldr1` type. I suppose the odd way you have written it, with the extraneous `\f ->` and `let`, is leading to confusion.

Comment: the problem is, your 2nd expression, `\f -> let ope x y = x . f . y`, is an invalid expression. Simple as that. Invalid expressions have no types. The correct parsing is `(\f -> (let {ope x y = x . f . y} in (foldr1 ope xss)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with the function

```
fun xss = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss
```

I'll rewrite this as

```
fun xss f = foldr1 ope xss
    where ope x y = x . f . y
```

So we start with `foldr1`:

```
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

So we can break down

```
foldrl1
    ope    -- (a -> a -> a)
    xss    -- [a]
```

So `ope :: a -> a -> a`, this is really useful to know since it simplifies the types of `x` and `y` to be restricted entirely to `a`, or put another way they both have the same type.  Since they're both functions (as required by `.`), instead of unifying their types the long way I'll just say that `x, y :: b -> c`

```
ope x y =    x     .    f     .    y
--        (b -> c) . (s -> t) . (b -> c)
```

I've left `f`'s type as unknowns right now, other than specifying that it has to be a function.  Since we know that `x` and `y` have the same type, we can now say that `y`'s output type is the same as `f`'s input type, so `s ~ c`, and `f`'s output type has to be the same as `x`'s input type, so `t ~ b`, so we get

```
ope x y =    x     .    f     .    y
--        (b -> c) . (c -> b) . (b -> c)
```

So now we can fill `fun`'s signature.  We already know the type of `xss`, it's `a ~ b -> c`, and since `foldr1`'s output type is also `a`, we get

```
 fun :: [b -> c] -> (c -> b) -> (b -> c)
```

And indeed this is the type that `GHCi` gives us

Answer (score 1):

Here's the derivation.

```
fun xss = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss

fun xss f = foldr1 ope xss
   where
      ope x y = x . f . y                                      y :: a -> b
              =     y   >>>   f   >>>   x                      f :: b -> c
                  a -> b    b -> c    c -> d                   x :: c -> d
              ::  a  ------------------->  d

ope          x         y    ::  a->d
ope    ::  (c->d) -> (a->b) -> (a->d)

foldr1 :: (  a1   ->   a1   ->   a1  ) -> [ a1 ] ->   a1       c ~ a, d ~ b
          ((a->b) -> (a->b) -> (a->b)) -> [a->b] -> (a->b)     a1 ~ a->b
foldr1                ope                  xss   :: (a->b)

fun      xss       f    ::  a->b
fun :: [a->b] -> (b->a) -> (a->b)
```

Function composition is associative: `f . (g . h)` =~= `(f . g) . h`. That's why the expression `f . g . h` is well formed.

Just as `(.) :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)` creates a chain of two functions feeding one from another, the `f . g . h` expression creates a chain of three functions, each taking as input its predecessor's output.

It is sometimes easier to use `(.)`'s cousin, `>>>`, which just flips the order of arguments:

```
f . g === g >>> f
```

It is defined in `Control.Category`.